# dEliminate printing word with repating letters if not repeating in user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a file with word in each file. User is inputs some words and the script is supposed to print words out of the given words.
For example: "Donald Trump" output: ['lad', 'mould', 'trump', 'land', 'donald', 'dump']
But I can't come to solution how to eliminate printing words with repeated letters unless letter repeats in input so it won't print something like: laddd or dumpp etc.

```
letters = input('input words: ') #input words to generate words
letters = letters.replace(' ', '') #eliminate whitespace
letters= list(letters) #create a list out of given words
words = open('wordfile').read().splitlines()  #read the file with words
word_list=[]
print(".......................")
for word in words:
    if all(element in letters for element in word):  #if has letters from list
        print (word)
        word_list.append(word)
print(word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

check is trying to see every letter in word removed from list of limited letters provided `##  i.e letters.remove(i.lower() i here is the letter in word ##` , i.e in your example *donaldtrump*, now as example if **laddd** comes the letter ***d*** will be removed twice from *donaldtrump* while removing third time it will throw exception (in this case **return False**) because in *donaltrump* there is no 3rd d. I hope this helps

```
def check(word,letter):
    letters = list(letter)
    try:
        for i in word:
            letters.remove(i.lower())
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False

letters = input('input words: ') 
letters = letters.lower().replace(' ', '') 
words = open('wordfile').read().splitlines()  
word_list=[]
print(".......................")
for word in words:
    if(check(word,letters)):
        word_list.append(word)
print(word_list)
```

Comment: Had to correct line 16. It works but your function overgrows me @yash , I don't get how the words letters are checked with list letters.Point taken about "ladd", typo, I've changed it for "laddd".